Control string of transistors to decide how many in line are activated
I've been working on a circuit for a robotic arm that uses a large amount of joints to move.

As you can see, each terminal has a transistor in front of it to control whether it activates or not. The simple way to do this would be to wire the base of each transistor to a GPIO pin on the Pi I'm using for this project. However, this would make it needlessly complicated, so I was wondering if there was a way to connect the base on each transistor to a single GPIO pin and then be able to control which transistors in along the wire are activated.
I would never need to activate an individual terminal, just ones in a line, like activating Q1 and Q2, or Q1, Q2, and Q3. If this isn't a possibility, that would be fine, but it would be preferable if it was.

Any other approach is just going to be even more complicated than a GPIO pin per transistor. At some point you are going to need something conencted to each transistor.

Looks like an XY problem, you've come up with a solution (useful clue, stacking transistors like that is rarely a good idea) to a problem and then asked how to make it work rather than asking how to solve the actual problem. Try describing the problem you're trying to solve and then someone may be able to offer a better solution.

What do you mean by "makes it needlessly complicated"? Do you mean the physical circuit, the code, the wiring, etc? Because none of that seems like it would be very complicated to me, but if it does to you than maybe consider using a GPIO expander IC instead.

@InBedded16 it's because I don't want to have 10+ wires going down the arm

From the comments, it seems like your goal is to minimize the number of wires between the physical circuit that houses the transistors, and the Pi that controls them. I would therefore recommend using a GPIO expander IC on the transistor circuit. If you use one that communicates via I2C, than all you need is 3 wires from the Pi to have control of potentially hundreds of GPIOs - depending on how many IOs the IC has, whether it has configurable I2C addresses, and whether you add in an I2C mux. Other serial protocols would obviously work as well.

Depending on the size of the robot and the electrical environment, it might be worth considering something like CAN for the increased resiliency.

Normally, this would be an excellent option. I guess what I didn't explain very well, however, is that each of the shown transistors would be in a separate joint of the arm, so  I would still have to connect each one to the expander and then to the Pi, which would still mean I would have at least 10 cables going to the expander.

This seems to be a follow-up to your previous Powering a certain amount of objects in a sequence based in the input voltage.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Figure 1.
You have little option other than to switch solenoid power as shown in Figure 1. If you don't have enough GPIO then use an expander IC or breakout board and send the data serially to the expander (only requires one or two GPIO pins) and one output from the expander to each switching transistor.
